# going back to the main menu after doInBackground is done

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using some background asyncTask, where I send a a post request to update an item in the data base.

After  the "doInBackground" stage is done, I want to return back to the main menu because the items are not yet updated (after the change in the data base) .

What is the best way to go back to the main menu (2 screens back)?

I have solved it by using the method onActivityResult and sending between the activities a result code that signify that  it can finish each activity untill reaching the last required activity and then reload the last activity with :

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What is your 'main menu'? And where did you start your asynctask from?

Comment: You never told that you went to 'another menu'. And in which 'menu' are you when the asynctask has finished? What do you mean with screens?

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask`s have three methods and they are called in sequence one after the other when you call execute on the object of your `AsyncTask`

[image]

after the `doInBackground()` method will finish its work, your `onPostExecute()` method of the AsyncTask will be called.Override that method and Check the recieved response,If valid response received than call the `intent` just like you do for going from one activity to the other to your main Menu,else you can have your other options.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityClass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanx but I don't want to start a new intent .. I want to return to the same intent I had..

Comment: If you could tell me , why you don't want to do that?so that I can help :)

Comment: well it's just that when I tried your way I did got the required screen.. but then I got some problems with the communication with the server ..   I ll have to look at it more carefully..

Comment: what about using the method onActivityResult?